# How to solve "Get data from file XXX.xxx failed!" error in cocos2d-x win32 project?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Recently I am using git to manage my cocos2d-x win32 project. However when I `git clone` my code in another computer. I met the `Get data from file XXX.xxx failed!` error. I checked a lot of questions, there were no exact answers to this question. So I share my solution here.

PS.I am using visual studio 2012 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your project->Properties->Debugging->Working Directory and change it to `$(ProjectDir)..\Resources` . And make sure your Resources is located at exact the place.